Restrict Mac with Touch ID to unlock only via password
Is there a way to prevent a Mac to unlock via TouchID and use password for authentication instead?

You could just not set a fingerprint.

Are you trying to prevent someone who can use Touch ID in other circumstances from unlocking with a fingerprint, or just trying to prevent Touch ID from being used at all? Or something else?

yes in other circumstances

Log out (under the Apple menu, or automatically after a certain time of inactivity).

Thanks to comments I realized I just need to send a message to force immediate log out which then requires password entry from the Lock Screen.
osascript -e 'tell application "loginwindow" to  «event aevtrlgo»'


Navigate to Apple Menu → System Settings... → Touch ID & Password and toggle off Use Touch ID to unlock your Mac.

